# cannot add named based virtual host

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost

my default virtual host which loads mainsite.com

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>


        DocumentRoot /var/www/
        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

another virtual host i added so when i go to myothersite.com it will load

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName myothersite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/myothersite.com

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have already added A record to my server ip for myothersite.com.

I restarted apache server but myothersite.com will not load. I get server not found.

when restarting i get  `[warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts`

Answer (score 1):

The following snippet should definitely work:

```
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
  DocumentRoot /var/www/
  # ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
  ServerName myothersite.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/myothersite.com
  # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

See how `NameVirtualHost` occurs only once while multiple `<VirtualHost>` directives can refer to it.

You *could* also use `NameVirtualHost *:80` or `NameVirtualHost <IP address>:80` if you wanted to be more specific. For details read the documentation on Apache httpd's [Name-based Virtual Host Support](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html).

Since you mentioned an error message like "Server not found" it is more likely that you have a DNS problem with your domain. Check again if the domains are properly setup in your name server.

Answer (score 0):

`<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName drongo.zarack.com

                ServerAlias drongo.zarack.com

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                DirectoryIndex index.html index.php

</VirtualHost>`

This is my working conf file.

Also, check the A record has propergated to your DNS Server by *nslookup myothersite.com* and confirm you are getting the value your expecting.

Just as a side, I have found to good station keeping, I put a CNAME for virtual names and A for actual hosts.

Comment: also i keep getting  [warn] NameVirtualHost *:0 has no VirtualHosts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use *:80 in both NameVirtualHost and VirtualHost:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: '*' as a wildcard is also a valid argument for NameVirtualHost and <VirtualHost> (see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost).